# Which program creates a C array given any file?

Tags: c, linux, arrays, unix

I remember seeing in the past a program that would take any file and generate a C array representing that file as output; it would prevent distribution of a separate file in some cases. Which Unix/Linux program does that?

Comment: That star a few pixels over there was made for this question

Answer (score 97, accepted):

[`xxd -i`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xxd/)

Comment: Edited to fit in less than 15 characters :p

Answer (score 16):

For large files, converting to text and then making the compiler parse it all over again is inefficient and unnecessary. Use `objcopy` instead:

```
objcopy -I binary -O elf32-i386 stuff stuff.o
```

(Adjust the output architecture as necessary for non-x86 platforms.) Then once you link it into your program, you can access it like so:

```
extern char _binary_stuff_start[], _binary_stuff_end[];
#define SIZE_OF_STUFF (_binary_stuff_end - _binary_stuff_start)

...

foo(_binary_stuff_start[i]);
```

Comment: In 2023 it may be necessary because C++ has constexpr std::string. You can parse the file at compile time and generate compile-time optimized data structures from it by embedding the char array in the source code. To work, you have to pack everything in the same compilation unit. Imagine providing a grammar and a parse generator directly from within the code. Also, xxd will not be necessary anymore after the #embed preprocessing directive.

Answer (score 8):

```
hexdump -v -e '16/1 "0x%x," "\n"'
```

would generate a C like array from stdin, but there is no declaration, no braces or good formatting.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is Unix/Linux question, but anyone viewing this that wants to do the same in Windows can use [Bin2H](http://deadnode.org/sw/bin2h/).

Comment: xxd is also available for windows.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is:

```
xxd -i -a filename
```