# Populate an array at compile-time from file

Tags: c++, arrays

I am cross compiling a program for a bare-metal environment and I want to have an array populated with the data I have stored in a file. Is there a way to do this read during compile-time?

Reason: Copy-pasting the data into the source seems ugly.

Comment: You can write a "driver" program that generates your source file. It'll read the data from the file and insert it into your source file.

Comment: You can integrate `xxd -i` or `objcopy` into your build. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155578/which-program-creates-a-c-array-given-any-file

Comment: I'm not sure but you can take a look at `constexpr` in c++11.

Comment: @Moberg http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xxd/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of your build process can be to run a program which takes the file as input and generates a C++ source file which defines it as an array, something like:

```
char arrayFromFile[] = {
    0x01, 0x02, 0x99, ...  and so on
};
```

The program itself could be part of your source code.

Then just compile that program later in the build cycle. For example, you may have the following `makefile` segment:

```
generate: generate.cpp
    g++ -o generate generate.cpp    # build data generator

data.cpp: data.dat
    generate data.dat >data.cpp     # create c file with data

prog: prog.cpp data.cpp
    g++ -o prog prog.cpp data.cpp   # create program from source and data
```

Answer (score 1):

Both GCC and Clang can be used to pack arbitrary files into a `.o` as static strings. There ends up being a bit of complexity around mapping what symbol names it uses to what the programmer thinks of that file as (particularly if the ["physical" and "logical" file paths in the build](https://github.com/bcsgh/bazel_rules/blob/master/cc_embed_data/make_emebed_data.cc#L71-L83) are not the same thing), but the core of the process is [demonstrated here](https://github.com/bcsgh/bazel_rules/blob/master/cc_embed_data/cc_embed_data.bzl#L73-L83) and, ignoring corner cases, boils down to:

```
gcc ... -Wl,--format=binary -Wl,$FILE1 -Wl,$FILE2 ...
```

(Projects that uses Bazel as their build tool may be able to just use the containing bzl rule directly.)